# Abrir un formulario desde el principal y modificar una variable del principal sin volver a crearlo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, diálogo, show

usando visual studio necesito modificar una variable que existe en el formulario principal desde uno secundario.

Para pasar del principal al secundario utilicé la propiedad ShowDialog para evitar cerrar el primero pues el secundario era pequeño y lo uso solo para cambiar una variable, pero no tengo idea de cómo modificar esa variable en el principal sin volver a crearlo.

[image: Código del botón en el formulario principal para acceder al secundario]
IMG 1. Código del botón en el formulario principal para acceder al secundario.

En el constructor del secundario paso la variable que quiero modificar para ponerla inicialmente como información

[image: Formulario padre(atrás) abierto y secundario encima]
IMG 2. Formulario padre(atrás) abierto y secundario encima

En el formulario secundario pretendo cambiar la llave precompartida para un algoritmo de encriptación que uso en el formulario principal para no usar la que tengo por defecto (lo cual no es relevante), pero necesito que ese cambio llegue a la interfaz principal que es donde llamo las clases de la lógica para ejecutar el algoritmo.
----NOTA: no se fijen en las interfaces, es un prototipo funcional

Comment: Brother, muestra tu código para que te podamos ayudar. También creo que necesitas entender cómo trabaja la programación orientada a objetos, simplemente tienes que acceder al objeto... para que te ayudemos, muestra tu código

Comment: No creo que sea un porblema de comprender la POO, auque es cierto que lo que intento hacer no es lo estándar en comunicación entre formularios. Código no teng mucho que mostrar porque no es ese el fuerte el problema, pero explicaré nuevamente la situación con 2 imágenes para ver si se entiende mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar variables entre formularios puedes utilizar 2 caminos, el primero, pasarlo por referencia:

En el formulario destino crea un método público así:

```c#
int ClaveActual = 0;

public void MostrarFormulario(ref int clave)
{
  this.ClaveActual = clave;
  this.txtClave.Text = clave.ToString();
  this.ShowDialog();
  this.ClaveActual = int.parse(this.txtClave.Text);
}
```

y en el botón de cambiar ponle el siguiente código.

```c#
public void CerrarFormulario()
{
  this.Close();
}
```

o sino para retornar un valor, obvia el ref y revuelve un valor:

```
public int MostrarFormulario(int clave)
{
  this.ClaveActual = clave;
  this.txtClave.Text = clave.ToString();
  this.ShowDialog();
  return int.parse(this.txtClave.Text);
}
```

y en la forma que llamas al formulario sería mas o menos así:

```
ChangeWin objFormulario = new ChangeWin();
//Por referencia;
objFormulario.MostrarFormulario(ref Clave);
//Por valor:
int NuevaClave = objFormulario.MostrarFormulario(Clave);
```

Comment: Gracias me funciona perfecto, solo un detalle, según como diseñé la interfaz secundaria en la función mostrarFormulario el return no sería del mismo textbox sino del otro...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Creo que ni siquiera es necesario usar eventos:

En tu formulario secundario agregas una propiedad y su correspondiente campo:

```
private int newKey;
public int NewKey { return newKey;}
```

Luego, en donde tienes el código del botón aceptar:

```
private void BotonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newKey = // obtienes la nueva key
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

Por último, cuando mandas llamar al formulario secundario:

```
var win = new Change_Key();
if (win.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     var nuevaKey = win.NewKey();
     // aquí ya puedes actualizar la "key" de formulario
}
```

Si quieres que el cambio se produzca en tiempo real antes de cerrar el segundo formulario puedes usar eventos.

Creas un evento así:

```
public class KeyChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public KeyChangedEventArgs(int keyValue)
    {
        KeyValue = keyValue;
    }

    public int KeyValue { get;}
}
```

En tu formulario secundario agregas el evento asi:

```
public class Change_Key: Form
{
    public event EventHandler<KeyChangedEventArgs> KeyChanged;
```

Y en donde cambies el valor en ese mismo formulario mandas invocar el evento:

```
var nuevaKey = // obtienes la nueva key desde donde se ha modificado
KeyChanged?.Invoke(this, new KeyChangedEventArgs(nuevaKey));
```

Y ya nada mas queda engancharse al evento desde el formulario principal:

```
var win = new Change_Key();
win.KeyChanged += (s , e) => {
    var nuevaKey = e.KeyValue;
    // aquí ya puedes actualizar la "key" de formulario principal a como la ocupes.
};
win.ShowDialog();
```